# Handling WebApi Error HttpResponseMessage client side

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm having issues dealing with a http error response from webapi when there are ModelState errors, namely the fact that 'ModelState' isn't a collection but properties so I can't loop through them.

I'm struggling to find any information on how others are dealing with this, it must be a common use case?

**Controller**

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
```

**Resulting JSON**

```
{  
    "readyState":4,
    "responseText":"{\"Message\":\"The request is invalid.\",\"ModelState\":{\"model.Property1\":[\"'Property1' should not be empty.\"],\"model.Property2\":[\"'Property2' should not be empty.\"],\"model.Property3\":[\"'Property3' should not be empty.\"]}}",
    "responseJSON":{  
      "Message":"The request is invalid.",
      "ModelState":{  
         "model.Property1":[  
            "'Property1' should not be empty."
         ],
         "model.Property2":[  
            "'Property2' should not be empty."
         ],
         "model.Property3":[  
            "'Property3' should not be empty."
         ]
      }
    },
    "status":400,
    "statusText":"Bad Request"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i'm using

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(k => ModelState[k].Errors)
                          .Select(m => m.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
            }
```

then return the response

Comment: Ideally I would have liked to have kept using CreateErrorResponse and dealt with it in the client. However this is what I'm going to go with for now so I'll accept.